# How to properly configure web.config for IISnode with clientCache

Tags: node.js, azure, web-config, iisnode

I've read in a few answers [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505918/serving-static-files-from-iisnode-with-url-rewrite) that it's better to use the iisnode's static files configurations rather than let node.js handle it.

That's ok, but I just can't find a way to get it to work with the traditional configurarion for browse caching:

```
<staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
```

When I'm using the node'js normal browse cache, that's how it's configured (and working):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {maxAge: 86400000}));
```

My questions, than, are:

- Is it really better to use the iisnode static files serving system?
- Is there a way to make `<clientCache ...` to work in IISnode?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically gave up trying to use IIS to serve static files and started using the maxAge option of the default Express static middleware, but I quickly grew tired trying to setup Grunt workflows to make sure the names of my static files change when the contents change.

Ended up writing a bit of Node.js middleware called Electricity which I tried to make as a mostly drop in replacement to the default Express static middleware: https://github.com/mediocre/electricity

Comment: Great! I'll take a look! How can I use it with jade? it only has examples in ejs. Thanks